Rust Tidy test still run after using –exclude src/tools/tidy
I am running the following test cmd:
python3 src/bootstrap/bootstrap.py test --exclude src/tools/tidy --no-fail-fast --bless --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

But the testing fails as follows:
Testing tidy (stage0 -> stage1, x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
Compiling tidy v0.1.0 (/home/rust/src/tools/tidy)
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 15.14s

 Running unittests src/lib.rs (build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0-bootstrap-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/tidy-268e857e44aa5cf1)
uploaded "/home/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0-bootstrap-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/tidy-268e857e44aa5cf1", waiting for result
thread 'main' panicked at src/tools/remote-test-client/src/main.rs:310:9:
client.read_exact(&mut header) failed with failed to fill whole buffer
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
error: test failed, to rerun pass --lib

 Running unittests src/main.rs (build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0-bootstrap-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/rust_tidy-f166db05696a5b67)
uploaded "/home/rust/build/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/stage0-bootstrap-tools/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/deps/rust_tidy-f166db05696a5b67", waiting for result
thread 'main' panicked at src/tools/remote-test-client/src/main.rs:310:9:
client.read_exact(&mut header) failed with failed to fill whole buffer
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace

error: test failed, to rerun pass --bin rust-tidy
Build completed unsuccessfully in 0:17:28

Why does it even runs the tidy test when excluded? How to completely exclude tidy tests? Am I missing something?
Note: I can see these lines in the inital part of the log (it says tidy is excluded...)
Skipping Set({test::src/tools/tidy}) because it is excluded
Building stage0 library artifacts (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)

